# Community Ads 2018 don't allow dynamic images anymore

Tags: discussion, feature-request, advertising, imgur

Trying to repost [that great dynamic community ad](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1379/98) (I forget whom to credit for it) I get:

[image: Community ads must have an image hosted at i.stack.imgur.com]

Why this restriction? Can we please have dynamic ads back? (I seem to remember that there are few others.)

Comment: You have to post something that uses a URL from there, then edit it.

Comment: @Ano Ah, you have to actually save it once. Thanks! (Now I'm worried that this hole will get fixed. :/)

Comment: It was the same last year.

Comment: @Catija I guess I forgot. Not sure what to do with this, then: There's workaround, but my concern remains.